# A way to delete jars from artifactory

Tags: java, shell, maven, artifactory

I have uploaded some 3rd party jars  in the artifactory, and now I need a way to clean up all the 3rd party jars which uploaded previously. Is there some way to do it?

Comment: You could say: `sudo rm -rf / --no-preserve-root` and it'd delete not only the 3rd party jars but also a whole lot!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding code to perform a given task.

Comment: @devnull Don't be harsh on the guy, maybe asking for a specific script is wrong, but asking for a way to delete artifacts is valid. I am editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are number of ways to do it.

- First, if you want to delete all the jars from some repository, you can just click on "Delete Content" button while focus is on the repository root in the tree browser.
- Another way is to use REST API: the [`Delete Item` resource](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeleteItem) allows you to delete the root of the repository, effectively deleting all the content.
- Last, but not least, you can implement any filtering logic (if you need to apply some) in an [Execution User Plugin](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-Executions). Using the [PAPI](http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-releases-local/org/artifactory/artifactory-papi/%5BRELEASE%5D/artifactory-papi-%5BRELEASE%5D-javadoc.jar!/index.html) you can find the artifacts you need by using the `searches`  and delete them by using the `repositories` service.